# How to use history.push from Homepage to other components?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, history

I have a steady`Header` component for all the components below.
Inside the `Header` two buttons which I want them to switch 'Search' or 'Cart' components from the default 'Home' component.

I want to use `history.push({ pathname: 'somepath', state: searchResults });` to move to the two components I mention above (and even more other components in the future).

I searched a lot of how to `history.push' correctly and searched in *https://reactrouter.com* and more sites but saw only parts of each hook, nothing like that.

**Questions:**

1. How can I `history.push` at the parent component from the child component, aka from `Header` to `App`, so the `Home`/`Search`/`Cart` will be replaced.
2. How do I use the `state` in `history.push` at the `Search` component?

```js
function App(props) {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [itemsAmount, setItemsAmount] = useState('');

 return (
    <div>
 <Header settingResults={setSearchResults} itemsCartAmount= {itemsAmount} />
       <Route path='/'>
      <Home />
    </Route>
<Fotter/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This below with the history hook at the same component makes an error  - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

```js
 return (
    <div>
 <Header settingResults={setSearchResults} itemsCartAmount= {itemsAmount} />
  <Router>
        <Route path='/'>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/search'>
          <Search
            searchResults={searchResults}
            setItemsAmount={setItemsAmount}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/cart'>
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Router>
    <Fotter/>
    </div>
  );
```

How can I combine all of them together so my plan will work?

Comment: Can you please describe your use case more properly, it's not clear. do you want to navigate to `/search` or `/cart` from your `Header` component which is sibling(placed on the same level) of `Router`?

Comment: Hi @sathyareddy, I want the `Header` to stay permanent and by clicking it's buttons it will be transferred from `Home` component  to `Search` or `Cart` or any other component I'll choose. See my first code sample - `<Route path='/'>
      <Home />// This to replace
    </Route>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use "BrowserRouter" instead of "Router" only. It will solve the purpose.

OR, if you want to use "Router", you have to define history as well in the route file,

```
    import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
    const history = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={history}>
<Switch>
        <Route path='/'>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/search'>
          <Search
            searchResults={searchResults}
            setItemsAmount={setItemsAmount}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/cart'>
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
       <Switch>
      </Router>
```

you also need to use these two line of snippet in those file also where you want to use history.location

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Comment: Hi and thank Kumar ,with your code sample, is the ` history.push({ pathname: '/search', state: searchResults });` should to be outside the return inside a function ?

Comment: you can put it inside any event function... like click handler or load event.... best practice should be outside of the return function.